# How do I use Loop with Variable Range

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code, when I get to for each curCell in Range(i) it is not able to understand the Range that I am referencing. I receive a Method 'Range' of Object'_worksheet' failed. I know the current Range(i) is incorrect, but I have tried every variation and nothing seems to work.

Can someone please help me understand how to get my code to recognize Range1, then Range2, etc?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range, Range4 As Range
Dim curCell As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cCostingQSheet)

Set Range1 = ws.Range("E6:E9")
Set Range2 = ws.Range("E15:E19")
Set Range3 = ws.Range("E21")
Set Range4 = ws.Range("E23")

For i = 1 To 4

    For Each curCell In Range(i).Cells

        If Not WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(curCell) = True Then

            curCell.Value = 0

        Else

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each curCell In Range("E6:E9,E15:E19,E21,E23").Cells` would work the same way

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I was trying to avoid having the cells referenced within the code so that it would be easier to debug for the next person taking over. I had forgotten that you could set up a non-contiguous range in this way. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an array if you want a setup like that.   Here's how:

Replace your variable declaration statement

```
'Instead of your original
'Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range, Range4 As Range

'Use this:
Dim arrRanges(1 To 4) As Range
```

Then change how you set the ranges:

```
Set arrRanges(1) = ws.Range("E6:E9")
Set arrRanges(2) = ws.Range("E15:E19")
Set arrRanges(3) = ws.Range("E21")
Set arrRanges(4) = ws.Range("E23")
```

And when you loop through them, it looks like this:

```
        For Each curCell In arrRanges(i).Cells
```

Comment: Thank you, @tigeravatar ! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign an non-contiguous range to a range variable instead of using either 4 different range variables or an array of ranges (as @tigeravatar suggested in their excellent answer). Something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set R = ws.Range("E6:E9,E15:E19,E21,E23")
    i = 1
    For Each myCell In R.Cells
        myCell.Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, @John Coleman . This is another good option. I had forgotten that you could assign non-contiguous ranges to a single variable. Thank you for the reminder and solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would go a step further and

- Look at each range inside the overall range.
- use a variant array to process the range (where the range area is more than one cell), then dump back to the range.

*code*

```
Sub recut()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("E6:E9,E15:E19,E21,E23")

    For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
        If rng2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            x = rng2.Value
            For lngRow = 1 To UBound(x)
                For lngCol = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
                    If IsNumeric(x(lngRow, lngCol)) Then x(lngRow, lngCol) = 0
                Next
            Next
            rng2.Value2 = x
        Else
            If IsNumeric(rng2.Value) Then rng2.Value = 0
        End If
    Next rng2

End Sub
```